# Angular 6 change colors sequentially when (click) the div generated with *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a color-array with different `colors[]`. What I want is to change the `background-color` of the div sequentially according to the colors inside the `Array`, when user clicks on it. So far I get the random color from the `Array` instead of sequential color and it changes the colors of all `div`s instead of changing the selected div.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; index as i" [style.background-color]="changeColour()"  (click)="changeColour()"></div>
```

component.ts

```
changeColour() {
  this.ranCl = this.colorarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.colorarray.length)];
  return (this.ranCl);
}
```

Comment: I have posted solution on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4pgkyu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html please check below answer also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using **Renderer2**

You can pass the template reference as the parameter of the function. The HTML code will be like this-

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; index as i" 
(click)="changeColour(i, someVar)" #someVar>{{item}}</div>
```

And you can change the style by Renderer2. In `ts` you have to implement like this-

```
  import {Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

  items = ['aaa','bbb','ssss'];
  color = ['#00FFFF','#008080','#0000FF','#000080'];

  constructor(private rd: Renderer2) {}

  changeColour(i,someVar){
   this.rd.setStyle(someVar,'background-color',this.color[i]);
  }
```

See live here- 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-renderer2-row

Comment: Thanks @Shofol you saved my day Renderer2 is what I needed. With the help of other answers I can get it done. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a counter and fetch the color accordingly. You can add displaycolor property which will update color in DOM

```
private counter = 0;
changeColour() {
    if(counter > this.items.length){
      this.counter = 0;
    }
    this.ranCl = this.colorarray[this.counter];
    this.items.forEach(function(item, index){
      item.displaycolor = '';
      if(index === this.counter) {
         item.displaycolor = this.ranCl;
      }
    });
    this.counter++;
  }
```

**Template:**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; index as i" [style.background-color]="item.displayColor"  (click)="changeColour()"></div>
```

Comment: I get this part. But it applies to every div instead of selected div

Comment: Updated answer based ur need

Comment: It changes the color in next div not in the current div. I want to change the color until I get the color I need. Then click the next div and do the same. Thank you very much for your attention on this

Answer (score 0):

You should change the index of the array sequentially. I created a property called colorIndex which increments everytime the user clicks the div. If the colorIndex is greater than the array length then it will be set to 0

```
colorIndex = 0;
changeColour() {
  if(this.colorIndex > this.colorarray.length) {
    this.colorIndex = 0;
  }
  const ranCl = this.colorarray[this.colorIndex++];
  return (ranCl);
}
```

Comment: I get this part. But it applies to every div instead of selected div

Comment: try to change the ranCl from property to const

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply pass the index as a dynamic entity to get color from the array like this -

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; index as i" 
[style.background-color]="colorarray[i]"  (click)="changeColour()">
</div>
```

Comment: I want to change the color when I click on div

Answer (score 0):

To achieve solution that you want please see below code

**AppComponent.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  colorarray = ['#342342', '#532332', '#FF00FF'];
  ranCl = '#FFF';
  items = [
    { isClicked: false, color : "#FFF" },
    { isClicked: false, color : "#FFF" },
    { isClicked: false, color : "#FFF" },
  ];

  changeColour(index) {
    this.items[index].color = this.colorarray[index];
    // console.log(this.items);
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; index as i" [style.background-color]="item.color"  (click)="changeColour(i)"></div>
```

**[Here solution on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4pgkyu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: What I want is change the colors when I click until I get the color I need